# Proper way to match something with a bunch of slashes in it

Tags: javascript, regex

So I call upon a page and the page returns this

```
onload":["goURI(\"\\\/goto\\\/3318250268968\\\/?context=edited\");
```

The number in between that can very on call to call. I basically want to do

```
onload":["goURI(\"\\\/goto\\\/<get this>\\\/?context=edited\");
```

With  of what I want to grab, and only that. What would be the best way to do this? I am awful with regex.

Comment: That's a very strange fragment. It's not a valid object initializer, but it looks like it's meant to be. Are you sure you've included the whole thing?

Comment: That isn't the whole thing, it returns a bunch of other things too. But I just need to get the information from that one snipplet.

Comment: @ Josh: But the snipplet doesn't make any sense, which makes it hard to explain how to extract from it.

Answer (score 0):

The string you provided can be matched using the following pattern.

```
onload":\["goURI\(\\"\\\\\\/goto\\\\\\/(.+?)\\\\\\/\?context=edited\\"\);
```

Comment: data2.match(/onload":\["goURI\(\\"\\\\\\\/goto\\\\\\\/(.+?)\\\\\\\/\?context=edited\\"\/);

gets an error

What is the best way to actually format it for .match()?